# onclick in tooltip not firing

Tags: javascript, onclick, tooltip

Please see the link:

http://www.stilgiyin.com/share.php?sshrsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.boyner.com.tr%2FCmsFiles%2FImages%2FProductImages%2FOriginal%2F654000%2F1_1262674.jpg

If you click on the jacket, you will see an alert "here". Looking at the page source, you'll see the onclick that is responsible for this alert.

If you hover over the jacket, you will see a tooltip. I used the jquery tiptip plugin for this tooltip. The plugin requires you to put the tooltip's content within a title attribute.

I'm trying to get an onclick event to fire when the user clicks on the large pink button inside the tooltip. However, it doesn't seem to be working, because the alert I set "intooltip" isn't popping up.

The code for the onclick is:

```
onclick="alert('intooltip'); clickstatistictit(this.rel); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outgoing', 'boyner.com.tr', '']); trackConv('995622692', 'JMHBCOzUgAQQpP7f2gM');"
```

I don't know if the problem is that I have double quotes around intooltip instead of single quotes. However, if I use single quotes, this closes the tooltip content, which begins with title='

Or maybe the issue is something completely different. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the double quotes inside your title attribute, otherwise you will get syntax errors in the onclick handler.

It might also be better to put your event handeling code inside a separate function in your header. You can then use just the function name inside the title attribute instead of the list of functions calls you are using now.

Comment: Hi Willem. I agree about a separate function. However, I don't understand what you mean by escape the double quotes...

Comment: I don't think I can post all of it. There's a lot. I am printing it with PHP. THe onclick part is like this: <?php echo "onclick=\"alert(\"intooltip\"); clickstatistictit(this.rel); _gaq.push([\"_trackEvent\", \"outgoing\", \"$store\", \"$cat\"]); trackConv(\"995622692\", \"JMHBCOzUgAQQpP7f2gM\");\" "; ?>

I'm trying to figure out how to echo an escaped double quote using PHP :)

Comment: it seems that replaceing the \" with &#039; has fixed the problem

Comment: That might work but much better would be to just escape the quotes

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, the reason is that you use double quotes inside other double quotes. When you check that pink button in firebug, the resulting code says:

```
onclick="alert("
```

so it's not interpreted correctly.

Comment: But I can't use
    onclick="alert('
because this closes the title=', and closes the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

The [tiptip jQuery plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) doesn't create a new child for every element with a tooltip. Instead it uses a general container and moves it accordingly, thus the tooltip is not a descendant of your element. Thereby the click event won't bubble to your elements onclick handler.

Note that tiptip isn't meant for such kind of tooltips. After all tiptip was originally meant for text tooltips.

Comment: Hi Zeta. Do you know if there's a workaround I can use? Or do you think I need to use a different tooltip library?